# C# - Write Data To A Stream + Read Data With Another Stream

Tags: c#, multithreading, stream

Right now I have a [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) and a [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx), 1 file that holds the (text) data, at least 2 threads. 1 thread is a listener and reads the data. The other thread writes stuff into the stream.

**Can I avoid using a file as the memory buffer ?**

I thought it might be possible to connect the 2 streams from both ends. But dunno how. I create the writer that writes to the file. Then I start a thread that creates a reader that reads from this file and does his work. It works but I want to avoid the file thingy.

---

```
// writer
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(new FileStream("text.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read));
writer.AutoFlush = true;
// reader
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new FileStream("text.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite));
```

Comment: it belongs to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @MikroDel What ? I can't ask questions about programming on stackoverflow anymore ? I don't have any problems with my code. I just need the right technique.

Comment: Look at codereview.stackexchange.com please - its a place to post code without problems (as you commented :)) To analyse it and post some proposals how to make it better

Answer (score 1):

I published something I called `ProducerConsumerStream` that will do this. It's an in-memory stream that allows one reader and one writer. It's a fixed-size circular buffer that allows a consumer to read as fast as the producer can write. See [Building a new type of stream](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=852).